# GrizzlyWebServer Replacement in Grizzly 2

Tags: grizzly

What is the replacement for GrizzlyWebServer in Grizzly 2? I need something compatible with Jersey 2.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer